# Consecutive rolls of a die whose face count increases by $1$ with each roll.

Tags: probability

The game starts with a dice with (let's say) $1000$ faces. Every roll, the die magically gets another face. So, after $1$ roll it has $1001$ faces, after another $1002$, and so on. Now the question is:

> What is the probability of rolling at least one $1$ in the first $x$ rolls?

Comment: What do you mean by "How high is the  chance to roll a 1 in x rolls"?

Comment: The probability of rolling a magic die with $n$ faces $m$ times and getting $1$ all of them is $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{n+k}$

Comment: Well, lets say you roll the dice 1000 times (and it gets another face after every roll), how high is the chance to roll a `1` in those 1000 rolls.

Comment: @barakmanos i mean a single 1, not all ones. And the thing is, every roll the dice gets another face, thats the tricky part

Comment: @tkausl Do you mean *precisely* one roll, or *at least* one roll? My answer below assumed the latter.

Comment: At least a single one.

Comment: @tkausl I substantially edited the question for clarity. Please check that it preserves your intended meaning and roll back any changes that do not.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Travis. English is not my native language and I'm very bad in writing and explaining something in english, sorry for that. I really appreciate your edit.

Comment: @tkausl You're welcome, that's part of what the editing process is for. (And for what it's worth, the original wording was comprehensible, just perhaps not entirely clear.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** If the die at first has $\require{cancel}F$ faces, then

- Since there are $F - 1$ faces that have a label other than $1$, the probability of *not* rolling $1$ on the first roll is
  $$\frac{F - 1}{F} .$$
- For the second roll, there are $F + 1$ faces and $F + 1 - 1 = F$ faces that have a label other than $1$. So, the probability of not rolling a $1$ on the second roll is
  $$\frac{F}{F + 1} .$$
  Since rolling $1$ on the first roll and rolling $1$ on the second are independent events, the probability of not rolling $1$ on either of the first two rolls is the product of the two above probabilities, namely,
  $$\frac{F - 1}{\cancel{F}} \cdot \frac{\cancel{F}}{F + 1} = \frac{F - 1}{F + 1},$$
- For the third roll, there are $F + 2$ faces and $F + 1$ of these have a label other than $1$. So, the probability of not rolling $1$ on the third roll is $$\frac{F + 1}{F + 2} ...$$

Comment: This helps i guess. Could you add another example for the third and forth roll please? I don't get why you remove the `-1` from the top and add `+1` to the bottom for the second roll and don't see where i have to go from there

Comment: I've added some more interstitial explanation and worked out part of the information for the the third roll, I think you'll get the idea from here.

Comment: Ooooh, so you add 1 above _and_ below the divider. Got it, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the complement of the propability to **not** get a 1, i.e.
$$p(x)=1-\prod_{k=1}^x(1-\frac{1}{999+k})= \frac{x}{999+x}$$